# Doctrine findOneBy method not working

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am creating small application with just two entities, Order and Shipment.

The Shipment entity is as follows: (methods removed to keep it short)

```
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $username
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string $password
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var integer $order_id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="integer")
 */
private $order_id;

/**
 * @var smallint $payment_type
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="payment_type", type="smallint")
 */
private $payment_type;
```

In my controller I am trying to query using the `order_id` but my `findOneByOrderId` method is not working.

```
$orderExists = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('ShipBundle:Shipment')
                ->findOneByOrderId($orderId);

var_dump($orderExists);     die();
```

The error I get is:

```
Entity 'ShipBundle\Entity\Shipment' has no field 'orderId'. You can therefore not call 'findOneByOrderId' on the entities' repository.
```

If I am not wrong, Doctrine `find` methods join the variables at underscores and capitalize them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be findOneById() then?

Comment: Do you have a getter for order_id? Since this is a private property if you don´t have a getOrderId() method you will not be able to access it

Comment: @Carlos Thanks for the response. I have all the getter setter methods. I have not posted them to keep the question short. I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Cups No, I dont think so. findOneById would be for querying by id not order_id.

Comment: try ->findOneBy('orderId'=> $orderId);

Comment: @pomaxa It didn't work: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Comment: @pomaxa you were almost right. I have answered below. Thanks again

Comment: Do `findOneByOrder_id()` work ? :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with the hint from pomaxa and Doctrine2 documentation.

The correct code would be:

```
$orderExists = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('ShipBundle:Shipment')
                ->findOneBy(array('order_id' => $orderId));
```

explained at: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

Thanks everyone for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the inbuilt relationship capabilities of Doctrine2 instead of using an id of order in your entity **Shipment** manually
That way you would have a relationship Doctrine is aware of.

```
$orders = $shipment->getOrders();
```

Look here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my entity, I have no relationships between both the entities. All I need is to query my Shipment entity using it's order_id variable.

Answer (score 2):

Problem in this line

> private $order_id;

Use it

> private $orderId;

It is ok. For db you will have order_id.

Comment: Indeed you need to follow Symfony's and Doctrine's conventions, else things don't work well.

Answer (score -2):

Just to clarify, the reason for the error was that you needed to pass an Array into the `findOneBy();`

This is wrong: , `->findOneByOrderId($orderId);` in

```
$orderExists = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('ShipBundle:Shipment')
                ->findOneByOrderId($orderId);
```

An array must be passed. `array('order_id' => $orderId)`

```
$orderExists  = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('ShipBundle:Shipment')
                ->findOneBy(array('order_id' => $orderId));
```

OR SHORTHAND `['order_id'=> $orderId]` as long as you are in PHP >= 5.4

```
$orderExists  = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('ShipBundle:Shipment')
                ->findOneBy(['order_id'=> $orderId]);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong, he can use both. And findOneByXyz() accepts scalars.

The problem is field name $order_id that should be $orderId.